# Shared Native instance of worker and main thread

Tags: nativescript

I want to make a progressbar file download. Calculation of an already loaded file needs to be done in a separate thread. That's just not clear how to pass a variable `manager`

main.js

```
import * as MyWorker from 'nativescript-worker-loader!~/utils/DownloadManagerProgress.js';

const { DOWNLOAD_SERVICE } = android.content.Context;
const manager = app.android.context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

const worker = new MyWorker();
worker.postMessage({ manager });

worker.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event);
};

worker.onerror = function (err) {
  console.log(`An unhandled error occurred in worker: ${err.filename}, line: 
  ${err.lineno} :`);
  console.log(err.message);
};
```

DownloadManagerProgress.js

```
import 'globals';


global.onmessage = (msg) => {
  const { manager } = msg.data;
  const query = new android.app.DownloadManager.Query();
  const cursor = manager.query(query);
};
```

Error:

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property \'query\' of undefined'

---

If I create an object in the worker, an error also appears

DownloadManagerProgress.js

```
import 'globals';
import * as app from 'application';

global.onmessage = (msg) => {
  const { DOWNLOAD_SERVICE } = android.content.Context;
  const manager = app.android.context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

  const query = new android.app.DownloadManager.Query();
  const cursor = manager.query(query);
};
```

error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property \'getSystemService\' of undefined'

Сould help me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure why you might want to use download manager in a worker, by default it handles the download on background and doesn't harm your main thread. Moreover I think there are plugins which handles the download manager native code for you, checkout the market place.

Comment: I want to display the progress bar loading, so you need to use a loop that will constantly check the number of bytes loaded. That's how it's done on java [example](https://gist.github.com/tolmachevroman/2c3358faad90aa802dfb)

Comment: You already have necessary callbacks implemented by the plug-in (nativescript-downloader or nativescript-downloadmanager), you might just have to update the progress bar in that callback.

Comment: Thank's. It's work:```import * as utils from 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils'; const manager = utils.ad.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);```